# jQuery – loop DOM objects and pass them to dataLayer(json?)

Tags: jquery, json, google-datalayer

I have to manually create my events for GA4, and I have a little knowledge of jQuery.
I'm trying to loop through my DOM elements and pass the data from them to dataLayer (as I understand, that's json format?), that Google wants.
My code looks like that (in simplified form):

```
function viewCartGA4() {
  let product = $('table.products tbody tr');
  dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
  dataLayer.push({
    event: "view_cart",
    ecommerce: {
      currency: "xxx",
      items: [
      {
        item_name: product.children().data("name"),
        item_id: product.children().data("code")
      }
      ]      
    }
  })
}
```

If there's only one table row, there's no problem, but how can I pass more than one to an array *items* required by Google?
Tried to create an $.each function inside an array, to no avail.

---

I'm not a pro by any means, it just happened, that I cover things like that in my company. Tried to look through the Internet, I found only the opposite situation (to pass json data to the DOM elements/content). I have just the basic understanding of coding and coding concepts. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the supplied code works when there is a single table row, for many rows you would need to loop over each and map it to the desired object. jQuery has [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method that can used:

```
function viewCartGA4() {
  // map each table row (tr) to an object
  const items = $('table.products tbody tr').map(function () {
    return {
      item_name: $(this).children('[data-name]').data("name"),
      item_id: $(this).children('[data-code]').data("code")
    };
  }).get(); // .get() turns this from a jQuery wrapped array into an unwrapped one
  
  dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
  dataLayer.push({
    event: "view_cart",
    ecommerce: {
      currency: "xxx",
      items: items // assign the mapped `items`
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow! That did the job! I can work with this (since the original code is a little bit more complex). Thanks!